# Mysql query to get result with condition

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Hi how can I make query like. If user is logged in get all the review even if it is not published so that logged in user can edit or delete this own review and also all other published review should be displayed in order by ID.

I am using CodeIgniter active record. Query is as follows where publish = 1 is, it is seen and publish = 0 is not seen.

```
 $this->db->select('user.name,user.image,product_review.*')->join('user', 'user.user_id = product_review.user_id');
 if ($this->session->userdata("is_logged_in")) {
        $this->db->where('product_review.user_id', $this->session->userdata("user_id"));
        $this->db->where('publish', '0');
 }
 $this->db->where('publish', '1');
 $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
 $this->db->order_by('review_id', "DESC");
 $query = $this->db->get("product_review");
```

But with this query I am not able to get any result.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, you have to use `or` condition

try this query

```
$this->db->select('user.name, user.image, product_review.*');
$this->db->from('product_review');
$this->db->join('user', 'user.user_id = product_review.user_id');
if ($this->session->userdata("is_logged_in")) {
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata("user_id");
    $this->db->where("(product_review.user_id = $user_id or product_review.publish = 1)");
} else {
    $this->db->where('product_review.publish', '1');
}
$this->db->where('product_review.product_id', $product_id);
$this->db->order_by('product_review.review_id', "DESC");
$result = $this->db->get()->result();
```

[click there](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f9c90/2) for demo

Comment: This is not the requirement. I want to get all review even if the publish is 0 and user is logged in ie, only the review of the logged in user even if it is not publish or publish = 0. But all other publish = 1 review as well.

Comment: you want the review of login user publish 0 or 1 and along with publish 1 of there users correct? if so, this code `$this->db->where("(product_review.user_id = $user_id or product_review.publish = 1)");` is checking for product_review.user_id is of current login user, if review is not of current user, then `product_review.publish = 1` for other user's review. please check its an `or` condition. try this code.